# Override Singleton in Laravel Container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to override a singleton service set in the core of the Laravel framework?

e.g. I'm trying to rewrite the app:name command service '' with the following provider:

```
use Hexavel\Console\AppNameCommand;
use Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStarting;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class NameCommandProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->listen(ArtisanStarting::class, function ($event) {
            $event->artisan->resolve('command.app.name');
        }, -1);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('command.app.name', function ($app) {
            return new AppNameCommand($app['composer'], $app['files']);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm 100% everything is working due to extensive checks put no matter what order I put my service provider (above or below ConsoleSupportServiceProvider) it still loads the original AppNameCommand over my custom one.

**I've already got a work around BUT** it would be nice to know about the behaviour of singleton services for the future if this is at all possible? (This is using Laravel 5.2 if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's actually a cleaner way to do this. You basically want to extend a core binding, which can be achieved by using the `extend` method:

```
$this->app->extend('command.app.name', function ($command, $app) {
    return new AppNameCommand($app['composer'], $app['files']);
});
```

[Jason Lewis](http://jasonlewis.me) has a really nice article regarding Laravel's IoC on [Tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/digging-in-to-laravels-ioc-container--cms-22167). Make sure to check it out ;)

Comment: Laravel-7; For me `rebinding(...)` did work, as I wanted to replace existing singleton-class, but `extend(...)` would cause my singleton-class' method to never get reached (and already `make`d singleton-class would be called instead, silently without error).

Comment: Should this `extend`/`rebinding` be in my package's service provider `boot` or `register` I'm trying to overwrite `command.migrate.fresh`, but both did not work for me

Answer (score 6):

I looked at this case and it seems it not the easy one. If you use `singleton` in your custom Provider it will be finally overridden by default provider (deferred one) so it seems it won't be the way.

After checking that simple approach doesn't work, what you need to do in such case is analysing what is happening when Laravel registers this command.

So in your case you search first for `command.app.name` - you see it's in `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider` and there is method `registerAppNameCommand` you would like to probably override.

So now you look for occurences of `ArtisanServiceProvider` to see where it's launched - you see it's in `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` in `$providers` property (which you would like probably to change).

So finally you should look for occurrences of `ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` and you see it's in `config/app.php`.

So what you need to do in this case:

- Change in `config/app.php` - change `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` into your custom one `ConsoleSupportServiceProvider`
- In your custom one you should extend from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider` but change in `$providers` from `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider` into your custom `ArtisanServiceProvider`
- finally create custom `ArtisanServiceProvider` which will extend from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider` where you override `registerAppNameCommand` using custom class in `singleton`

Using this way you will achieve your goal (I've verified it that custom class will be used running command `php artisan app:name`).

Alternatively you might want in your custom `ArtisanServiceProvider` remove `'AppName' => 'command.app.name',` from `$devCommands` and use your custom service provider as you showed where you register your singleton but I haven't tried this approach.

Comment: Yes I figured this would work as an override and the only way to do it but to be honest it's a very clunky option which is a shame. I can also just override the command by resolving it with e.g the new command will replace app:name it's just might lead to potential problems if others don't know that command.app.name service is redundant

Comment: Yeah, you are right, there are some functionalities in Laravel for which you need to make many changes to make them work but in other frameworks it's often even worse :)